# Newbie: Errors in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm really newbie in iOS and I have to handle a complicated situation. I was given an iPhone app developed by someone and I have to make it work. The guy who developed it has told me that it worked, but sometimes crashed in an iPhone. I've never developed using iOS and I don't really know how this app works.

Well, when I open the app with Xcode, the first problem that I detect is some errors with the references. The app uses the project CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj. I've added again this project and solved the references (I've followed some other posts like this one: http://www.jaysonjc.com/programming/pie-chart-drawing-in-iphone-using-core-plot-library.html).

I want to test it with the simulator (I don't have an iPhone yet). I have a doubt here...should I use iOS Device, or iOS Simulator as Base SDK? Firstly I chose iOS Simulator, but it appeared a problem with Cocoa.framework (it turned into red).

Anyway, using iOS Device as Base SDK, I build the project and it says "Build failed (59 errors, 3 warnings)". I check out the errors, and most of them are "Expected specifier-qualifier-list before ..."

Can anyone help me? This is more or less the situation, but I can provide more specific details if they're needed.

I'm sorry if I'm talking about something really basic, but I've been trying to solve it for 2 weeks and I give up. I've tried to talk to the guy, but he's not really helpful..

---

Thanks for the replies!

By the way, I didn't say it and I don't know if it's relevant or what it means. The guy has a directory called "Libraries" where it's stored the CorePlot. The files there are the same than if you download the CorePlot project from other source. The only exception is a folder called "SDKBuild", which contains files like "build.sh", "iphoneos-SDKSettings.plist" or "iphonesimulator-SDKSettings.plist". I'm really newbie, so it's probably obvious, but I have no idea...

Answer (score 0):

just try to add CocoaTouch framework to your project.

and for base SDK use "latest iOS".

Comment: Do you mean the project CocoaTouch, or any other framework? I've already added again the project as I said above. The guy also had the "libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a" among the frameworks. It's red, cause the reference is different. It tries to find the file in ../ProjectName/build/Debug-iphoneos/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project name in 'group & files' set on the left of xcode. Choose add -> Existing Frameworks.

Find Cocoa.framwork and click add. Do this to all red colored framework.

Choose IOS Simulator as base SDK.

Try run it..

Comment: The problem is if I look for "Cocoa.framework", it's not listed in the list of available frameworks for Simulator - iOS SDK. Actually it's weird, cause even though I set iOS Device as Base SDK, in "Existing Frameworks..." it still says Simulator - iOS 4.1 SDK

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the app on simulator, you have to build with iOS simulator. The base SDK basically sets the OS version (this will be the same regardless of whether you are running the app on simulator or device). You should be chaining the build settings to device only if the device is connected and if you have installed the appropriate provisioning profiles.